# Iterate a program erasing datas in the original set

Tags: perl

I am trying to study an algorithm in which, given a list of numbers I must calculate a coefficient given by the ratio between the number of triangles founded in the data list and the minimum number of neighbors that a number has; for example, given the first two rows of the file:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 9
2 1 3
...
```

1. if the first element of a row appears in the other rows and if the first element of the subsequent rows appear in the row taken in exam then I found a link;
2. if the "*link*" exists, then I want to count how many times the other elements in the row taken in exam appear in the row where the link is present and print "*I have found z triangles*".

For example in this case when the program compare the first row and the second row and find that "*the link 1 2*" exists and found that there is 1 triangle made by the vertex 1,2,3.
In the algorithm I have to divide the number of triangles + 1 by the minimum number of element in each row - 2 ( in this case the minimum number come from the second line and the value is 3-2=1); the coefficient that I am looking for is then (1+1)/1 = 2;

The output file will be written as:

```
1 2 1
```

in which in the first two columns I find the element that makes a link and in the 3rd column the value of the coefficient;

Here is the code I've written so far:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use List::Util;

my $filename = "data";
open my $fh, '<', $filename or die "Cannot open $filename: $!";

my $output_file = "output_example";
open my $fi, ">", $output_file or die "Error during $output_file opening: $!";

my %vector;
while (<$fh>) {
    my @fields = split;
    my $root = shift @fields;
    $vector{$root} = { map { $_ => 1} @fields };
}

my @roots = sort { $a <=> $b } keys %vector;
for my $i (0 .. $#roots) {
    my $aa = $roots[$i];
    my $n_element_a = scalar (keys %{$vector{$aa}})-1;

    for my $j ($i+1 .. $#roots) {
        my $minimum;
        my $bb = $roots[$j];
        my $n_element_b = scalar (keys %{$vector{$bb}})-1;
        next unless $vector{$aa}{$bb} and $vector{$bb}{$aa};
        if ($n_element_a < $n_element_b){
            $minimum = $n_element_a;
        }else {
            $minimum = $n_element_b;
        }

        my $triangles = 0;
        for my $cc ( keys %{$vector{$aa}} ) {
            next if $cc == $aa or $cc == $bb;
            if ($vector{$bb}{$cc}) {
                $triangles++;
            }
        }

        my $coeff;
        my @minimum_list;           
        if ($minimum == 0){
            $coeff = ($triangles +1)/($minimum+0.00000000001);
        } else {
            $coeff = ($triangles +1)/($minimum);
        }
        say $fi "$aa $bb $coeff";
    }
}
__DATA__
1 2 3 4 5 6 9
2 1 3
3 1 2
4 1 5
5 1 4
6 1 7 8
8 6 7
9 1 10 11
10 9 11 12 14
11 9 10 12 13
12 10 13 14
13 11 12
14 10 12 15
15 14
```

I put the entire dataset at the end. The output file gives:

```
__OUTPUT__
1 2 2
1 3 2
1 4 2
1 5 2
1 6 0.5
1 9 0.5
2 3 2
4 5 2
6 8 2
9 10 1
9 11 1
10 11 1
10 12 1
10 14 1
11 13 2
12 13 1
12 14 1
14 15 100000000000
```

Now I would like to find the minimum value of the coefficient, identify the link(s) that present this lower value, erase this elements in the original dataset and repeat the same program on the "new" dataset.

For example in this case the links that present the minimum values are the `1 6` and the `1 9` with a coefficient of `0.5`. So now the program should delete in the file data the element "6" in the row that start with "1" and vice-versa and the same with the 9. So now the "new" dataset would be:

```
1 2 3 4 5
2 1 3
3 1 2
4 1 5
5 1 4
6 7 8
8 6 7
9 10 11
10 9 11 12 14
11 9 10 12 13
12 10 13 14
13 11 12
14 10 12 15
15 14
```

**What I am looking for is**:

1. How can I erase the elements that present the minimum coefficient's value from the dataset contained in the `data` file?
2. How can I iterate the processes N times?

---

To find the minimum from the output file I thought to add at the end of the program these lines:

```
my $file1 = "output_example";
open my $fg,  "<", $file1 or die "Error during $file1 opening: $!";

my @minimum_vector;
while (<$fg>) {
    push @minimum_vector, [ split ];
}

my $minima=$minimum_vector[0][2];
for my $i (0 .. $#minimum_vector){
    if($minima >= $minimum_vector[$i][2] ){
        $minima=$minimum_vector[$i][2];
    }
}
say $minima;
close $file1;
```

But it gives me an error with the `$minima` because I think I can't read from the same file that I have just created (in this case the output_example file). It runs if I compile in a different program.

Comment: @RickF `Use of uninitialized value in numeric ge (>=) at map2.pl line 82.`
`Use of uninitialized value $minima in numeric ge (>=) at map2.pl line 82.`
`Use of uninitialized value $minima in say at map2.pl line 89.`

Comment: That indicates that $minimum_vector[0][2] is undefined.  On taking a second look, you may need to call `close($fh);` before reopening it as $fg.  Also, your last line should be `close($fg)` - `close` takes a filehandle, not the file name.

Comment: even adding the `close($fh)` before opening the output_example datas still gives me the same error.

Comment: It looks like you may have rows with only 2 items?  In that case, `$minimum_vector[$i][2]` is going to be undefined.  A quick debugging print statement like `say join(':' $i,$minima, @{$minimum_vector[$i]})` placed at the top of the final loop might help.

Comment: If i write the code in a new file it works. If I add it in the bigger code it doesn't. The file on which it takes the values is the output file and is a 3 columns file as you can see in the output that i printed up.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to iterate would probably be to break your code up into subroutines.  This will also help clarify the code and track down exactly where problems might be occuring.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use List::Utils qw/min/;

sub load_initial_data {
    # open and read file, load it into an arrayref and return it.
}

sub find_coefficients {
    my $data = shift;
    my @results;
    foreach my $row (@$data) {
        # do stuff to calculate $aa, $bb, $coeff
        push @results, [$aa, $bb, $coeff];
    }
    return \@results;
}

sub filter_data {
    my $data = shift;
    my $coefficients = shift;
    my $min = min map { $_->[2] } @$coefficients;
    my @deletions = grep { $min == $_->[2] } @$coefficients;
    foreach my $del (@deletions) {
        delete( $data->{$del->[0]}{$del->[1]} );
    }
}

# doing the actual work:
my $data = load_initial_data(); 
my $coeffs;
foreach my $pass (0 .. $N) {
    $coeffs = find_coefficients( $data );
    $data = filter_data( $data, $coeffs );
    # You could write $data and/or $coeffs out to a file here
    # if you need to keep the intermediate stages
}
```

Comment: This is surely a better way to write the entire code, I will try to rewrite the entire code in this way and see if it works but I still don t know how to iterate and erase the links with the lower coefficient

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that I understand the actual algorithm, but I've edited the answer to take a crack at the deletion step.  Hopefully it'll get you on the right path at least.